# Largest k for $\displaystyle (a+b+c)^5 \ge\frac{k}{\sqrt{5}}(ab+bc+ca)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The following problem ate up my mind , If $a,b,c$ are distinct non-negative real numbers then find the largest value of the constant $k$ auch that the following inequality is satisfied,

$\displaystyle (a+b+c)^5 \ge \frac{k}{\sqrt{5}}(ab+bc+ca)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$

Comment: i would write$$\frac{(a+b+c)^5\sqrt{5}}{(ab+bc+ca)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}\geq k$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner that would not be an equivalent restatement as the denominator can be negative.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's better to find a maximum value of $k$ for which an inequality
$$(a+b+c)^5\geq k(ab+ac+bc)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$
is true for all non-negatives $a$, $b$ and $c$.
The answer is $25\sqrt5$.

Indeed, we can assume $k>0$ and $a\geq c\geq b$ and since

$(ab+ac+bc)(a-b)(a-c)(c-b)\leq(a-c)a^2c^2$ it's $(a-c)(a^2+ac+c^2-ab-bc)\geq0$,

it remains to find a maximal value of k, for which the inequality
$$(a+c)^5\geq k(a-c)a^2c^2$$

is true for all non-negatives $a$ and $c$ such that $a\geq c$.

It's enough to take $a>c>0$.

Let $a=xc$.

Hence, $x>1$ and $k_{max}=\min\limits_{x>1}\frac{(x+1)^5}{x^2(x-1)}=25\sqrt5$.

The last statement is obvious by AM-GM.

Comment: How do you show that the answer is $ 25\sqrt5$?

Comment: @GohP.iHan I fixed my post for you.

Comment: Please help me understand the lines $(ab+bc+ca)(a-b)(a-c)(c-b)\le (a-c)a^2c^2$ and from here to $(a+c)^5 \ge k(a-c)a^2c^2$

Comment: @Aditya Narayan Sharma if we'll prove that $(a+c)^5\geq k(a-c)^2a^2c^2$ so $(a+b+c)^5\geq(a+c)^5\geq k(a-c)^2a^2c^2\geq k(ab+ac+bc)(a-b)(a-c)(c-b)$